Karate mock server for only one resource on an API but call live for other resources to same API
{domain}/{context}/path1
{domain}/{context}/path2
{domain}/{context}/path3

Is it possible to only mock a request to resource ending in path3? While not mocking the response for resources 1 and 2? Where the requests go all to the same server?
I only am wanting to mock the request to one resource
From what I'm reading in the documentation and examples I haven't found anything close to that scenario

See row (5b) for this example: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example
The use of karate.proceed() is explained here.
